# Filter with AJAX in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have this datatable that presents data for each file in database and two data pick input DateFrom and DateTo :

```
<div class="form-group row ">
    <label asp-for="DateFrom" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="date" id="datefrom" asp-for="DateFrom" class="form-control" placeholder="DateFrom" />
        </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row ">
  <label asp-for="DateTo" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="date" asp-for="DateFrom" class="form-control" placeholder="DateTo" />
    </div>
</div>

@if (Model.Files.Count == 0)
{
    <caption>No Records Found</caption>
}
else
{

    <table id="files" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Thumbnail</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Number of downloads</th>
                <th>Genre</th>
                <th>File Type</th>
                <th>Published On</th>
                <th>Created On</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var file in Model.Files)
            {
                var thumbPath = "~/Thumbnails/" + file.ThumbnailPath;
                <tr>
                    <td><img style="width:80px;height:80px;" src="@thumbPath" asp-append-version="true" /></td>
                    <td><a asp-controller="files" asp-action="details" asp-route-id="@file.Id" class="text-dark">@file.Name</a></td>
                    <td>@file.DownloadCounter</td>
                    <td>@file.Genre.GenreName</td>
                    <td>@file.FileT.FileTypeName</td>
                    <td>@file.PublishedOn</td>
                    <td>@file.Year</td>
                    <td>@file.Author</td>
                    <td>
                        <a asp-controller="files" asp-action="QrCode" asp-route-id="@file.Id" class="btn btn-primary">Qr Code</a>
                        <a asp-controller="files" asp-action="EditFile" asp-route-id="@file.Id" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

So if DateFrom and DateTo are null nothing happens,but if they are not null i want to call this JSON function for each file.This function should return number of downloads in given period DateFrom and DateTo  so i want present that number instead of @file.DownloadCounter in data table,here is JSON function :

```
public JsonResult NumberDownloads(DateTime dateFrom,DateTime dateTo,FileModel file)
    {
        var stats = context.Statistic.Where(x => x.File == file).ToList();
        foreach(var item in stats)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            int Compare = DateTime.Compare(item.DownloadDate, dateFrom);
            int Compare2 = DateTime.Compare(item.DownloadDate, dateTo);
            if((Compare == 0) || (Compare2 == 0))
            {
                counter+=item.DownloadCounter;
            }else if ((Compare >= 0) && (Compare2 <= 0))
            {
                counter+=item.DownloadCounter;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
```

I need your help for how to return counter for each file,how to call function for each file and present it in datatable.

Comment: You have stored the number of downloads in the database each time, and then you want to display the number of downloads on the page?

Comment: I have stored in database ex. 10/21/2021 3(number of downloads) 54(Id of downloaded file). and this action works fine.So i have problem how to call this action onchange datetime pickers with that dates.